# Is there an algorithm for getting the boundary of a non-planar graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, graph-traversal

This is my first question here!

If I have a non-planar graph where every vertex connects to 3 other vertices, and where the edges are allowed to intersect, how do I find the boundary of the graph?

For example in the below graph, the pink line shows the boundary of the graph which needs to be found. The boundary should also not intersect, with it self.

[image: Graph boundary image]

Is there anything in graph theory which would help with this?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE! :-)

Comment: It looks like you have a *drawing of* a graph in the plane, since a graph by itself is just a set of vertices and a set of edges without any information about how the vertices are positioned. I would start by finding a convex hull, and then look for concavities by looking for shortest paths between adjacent pairs of hull vertices.

Comment: @j_random_hacker For some background, I am trying to find the boundary of the shadow created from a prism. I have projected all the edges onto the plane, and the boundary will be the boundary of the shadow. That's why it's a drawing of a graph.

Comment: @j_random_hacker also rather than finding the convex hull, would it not be faster to find a point on the boundary by getting the point with the minimum x position, and then selecting the outermost edge connected to that point (by selecting the edge with the largest dot product between the edge vector and the projected light vector), and then repeating this process at the next point, until it has traced the boundary?

Comment: Sounds like a good way! Both this and my approach require that every intersection of edges is represented by a vertex.

Comment: *non-planar graph* as in [can *not* be embedded in a plane such that the edges only intersect at vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planar-graphs)?

Comment: @greybeard yes, that non-planar. Except as others have pointes out this isn’t really a graph nor is it non-planar. I simply mean vertices at certain positions connected by edges which can intersect.